# How to configure Shovel plugin for two instances of RabbitMQ running on same machine

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

Sorry if this is repeated question but I am having hard time getting this to work even after doing a lot of search. Thanks for any help in advance!!.

I have two instances of RabbitMQ running inside docker container running on my machine as shown below.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                         NAMES
20c1ceda0013        datafyit/rabbitmq:shovel   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago         Up About an hour    4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 15671/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32791->5672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32790->15672/tcp   shovel-rabbit-snt
d467418754ef        datafyit/rabbitmq:shovel   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 15671/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32783->5672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32782->15672/tcp   shovel-rabbit-rcv
```

I am trying to configure a shovel plugin so that I can pass the messages from broker "shovel-rabbit-snt" through shovel plugin to "shovel-rabbit-rcv" broker and get it in my receiver code.
But I am not able to get the shovel to running state and getting following error  message always from RabbitMQ management UI.

```
{{badmatch,{error,econnrefused}},
 [{rabbit_shovel_worker,make_conn_and_chan,2,
                        [{file,"src/rabbit_shovel_worker.erl"},{line,238}]},
  {rabbit_shovel_worker,handle_cast,2,
                        [{file,"src/rabbit_shovel_worker.erl"},{line,63}]},
  {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1032}]},
  {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
```

My Shovel Configuration: -

```
Source  amqp://guest:guest@172.17.0.4:32791/
Sender
queue
Destination amqp://guest:guest@172.17.0.2:32783/
Receiver
queue
Prefetch count  ?
Reconnect delay 
Add headers ○
Ack mode    on-confirm
Auto-delete never.
```